# How to set up fingerprint unlock on Ubuntu 23.10?

Tags: dual-boot, fingerprint-reader

I can't find fingerprint sensors settings in Ubuntu 23.10 installed on my Dell Inspiron 5509. My fingerprint id is 27c6:538d. I've tried "settings > Users", but there is no fingerprint option there. Do I have to install separately? And also is it possible to set up face unlock on Ubuntu 23.10?